# Window function with lag based on another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark DataFrame:

| id | month | column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 200 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 800 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 1500 | 3 |
| A | 5 | 1200 | 0 |
| A | 6 | 1600 | 1 |
| A | 7 | 2500 | 2 |
| A | 8 | 2800 | 3 |
| A | 9 | 3000 | 4 |

I would like to create a new column, let's call it 'dif_column1' based on a dynamic lag which is given by column_2. The desired output would be:

| id | month | column_1 | column_2 | dif_column1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 200 | 1 | 100 |
| A | 3 | 800 | 2 | 700 |
| A | 4 | 1500 | 3 | 1400 |
| A | 5 | 1200 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 6 | 1600 | 1 | 400 |
| A | 7 | 2500 | 2 | 1300 |
| A | 8 | 2800 | 3 | 1600 |
| A | 9 | 3000 | 4 | 1800 |

I have tried to use the lag function but apparently I can only use an integer with the lag function, so it does not work:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("id")
sdf = sdf.withColumn("dif_column1", F.col("column_1") - F.lag("column_1",F.col("column_2")).over(w))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a row number column, and do a self join based on the row number and the lag defined in column_2:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("month")

df1 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w)) 

df2 = df1.alias('t1').join(
    df1.alias('t2'),
    F.expr('(t1.id = t2.id) and (t1.rn = t2.rn + t1.column_2)'),
    'left'
).selectExpr(
    't1.*',
    't1.column_1 - t2.column_1 as dif_column1'
).drop('rn')

df2.show()
+---+-----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id|month|column_1|column_2|dif_column1|
+---+-----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  A|    1|     100|       0|          0|
|  A|    2|     200|       1|        100|
|  A|    3|     800|       2|        700|
|  A|    4|    1500|       3|       1400|
|  A|    5|    1200|       0|          0|
|  A|    6|    1600|       1|        400|
|  A|    7|    2500|       2|       1300|
|  A|    8|    2800|       3|       1600|
|  A|    9|    3000|       4|       1800|
+---+-----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does work. I was just wondering if there would be another way without having to use the join since my dataframe has millions of rows and hundreds of columns and the operation is quite slow.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized something was missing from the join condition - check the edited answer. I'm afraid a join is needed. I guess a join is not too expensive compared to the lag window funtion, because I feel that they're essentially doing the same thing under the hood.

Comment: You are probably right. Thank you very much for your help, it was really helpful!